# Sharing variables and putting text box data into an array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm brand new to the subject and very lost. I have a text box on my webSite.  The *data entered into the textBox* will be *placed in an array*, and a *counter will increase*. Once the *counter reaches five*, you *cannot add more* to the array.

There will be a button to display all the names input into the array, which clears the array and the counter as well.

I have no idea how to order classes and methods in C#. I put the buttons inside of the main class so that I can share variables between them, but then I can't access the text box.

Some code is there because I'm trying to figure this out, but it may not belong in here.  The code is also rather bare because I'm just trying to figure it all out. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script runat="server"> 

public partial class Arrays
{
  private int Counter = 0;    

  protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.Text = (Int32.Parse(btn.Text) + 1).ToString();
    Label1.Text = "Enter Another student's name";
  }

  public void btnEnter_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Label1.Text = "Enter a student's name ";        
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: If we solve your school exercises then you still been lost.

Comment: I'm not looking for the answer, I'm looking for guidance.  I don't even know how to start this thing, my professor zoomed through it in class.

Comment: Ok, accepted, I will give you some guidance

Comment: Thank you very much.

I have a label that says, "Enter Student's Name"

When the button is pressed, a student's name will enter the array, the counter will increment, and the label will now say, "Enter Another Name"

I keep getting an error about nested and unnested.  How do I update the label if it's in the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to focus how you keep the previous data on the page.

From Post to Post you can store them ether on `ViewState` ether on a `control`.

As I see there is save the previous state on the `btn.Text`, that is not so cool, but ok accepted.

```
protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
     // the btn.Text keeps the number of post backs (enters of name).
    var Counter = Int32.Parse(btn.Text);
    Counter++;

    if(Counter >= 5)
    {   
        Label1.Text = "No more studen's names please";
    }
    else
    {    
        btn.Text = Counter.ToString();          
        Label1.Text = "Enter Another student's name";
    }
}
```

As you see is "store" the counter in the `btn.Text` an use this to know know many post have been done.

Some way like that you can use to store the entered names. I prefer to save it on viewstate and I can do that with this code.

```
const string cArrNameConst = "cArr_cnst";

public string[] cArrKeepNames
{
    get
    {
        if (!(ViewState[cArrNameConst] is string[]))
        {
            // need to fix the memory and added to viewstate
            ViewState[cArrNameConst] = new string[5];
        }

        return (string[])ViewState[cArrNameConst];
    }
}
```

and with that code you can add from 0->4 any name on `cArrKeepNames[]` on your code and have it after the post back, because is keep it on viewstate of the page.

```
protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    var Counter = Int32.Parse(btn.Text);

    // here you save the name in the array
    //  an magically is saved inside the page on viewstates data
    //  and you can have it anywhere on code behind.
    cArrKeepNames[Counter] = NameFromEditor.Text;

    Counter++;
    if(Counter >= 5)
    {   
        btn.Enable = false;
        Label1.Text = "No more studen's names please";
    }
    else
    {  
        btn.Text = Counter.ToString();

        Label1.Text = "Enter Another student's name";
    }
}
```

a simple code like that can read the array at any time:

```
foreach (var One in cArrKeepNames)
    txtOutput.Text += "<br>" + One;
```

I test it and is working good.

Comment: Aristos, thank you very much!  I'm going to study this and hopefully my C# skills will become stronger.

Comment: @user1657478 well I hope it will, because if they hire you on a company you can not ask me to go to work for you :)